# How to get only one element in xpath per tag?

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I am trying to extract attributes from a website, but get empty elements.

Using this code within srapy shell:

```
fetch('https://www.chronext.de/breitling/galactic/w7234812-a785-249s-a12d-4/C79467')

from w3lib.html import remove_tags
[remove_tags(w).strip() for w in response.xpath('//table[@class="compact margin-top-half"][1]/tr/td[2]/text()').extract()]
```

I am getting:

```
['C77316', '279175', 'Damen', 'Automatik', '28\xa0mm', 'Roségold', 'Roségold', 'Saphirglas', '', '', '', '2018', 'Originale Box', 'Originale Hersteller Papiere', 'CHRONEXT Echtheitszertifikat', 'Zusätzlich zur Herstellergarantie erhalten Sie eine 2-jährige CHRONEXT Garantie ab Kaufdatum.']
```

Which is surprising, as I aimed for the second box with /div[2] but received elements from both boxes instead.

I also tried this:

```
[x.strip() for x in response.xpath('//div[@class="row force-inside-container-behavior"]/div[2]/table/tr/td[2]/text()').extract()]
```

which returns this:

```
['', '', '', '2018', 'Originale Box', 'Originale Hersteller Papiere', 'CHRONEXT Echtheitszertifikat', 'Zusätzlich zur Herstellergarantie erhalten Sie eine 2-jährige CHRONEXT Garantie ab Kaufdatum.']
```

My goal is to get a dictionary of key/value pairs. E.g. "condition" = "good". The first box was without problems, then I thought let's get the second box seperatly and extend the list.

The key is not the problem, but the value I am trying to get returns those 3-4 empty elements which will bring the order out of sync once I pull the key/value together later on. Removing the 3 empty fields might not be a good option as another page on this site might be slightly different.

How can I get only one element per key-value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to extract those specifications?

This is 100% working code that extracts key-value pairs from specs table

```
specs = {}
for td in response.css(".specifications .col.s12.l5")[0].css("tr"):
    specs[td.css("td")[0].css("::text").extract_first()] = td.css("td")[1].css("::text").extract_first()

{u'Uhr f\xfcr': u'Damen', u'Glas': u'Saphirglas', u'Artikel\xadnummer': u'C79467', u'Gr\xf6\xdfe (Geh\xe4use)': u'29\xa0mm', u'Material (Geh\xe4use)': u'Edelstahl', u'Werk': u'Quarz', u'Armband': u'Kautschuk', u'Referenz': u'W7234812.A785.249S.A12D.4'}
```

Comment: Interesting aproach. I don't get any result though: >>> specs = {}
>>> for td in response.css(".specifications .col.s12.l5")[0].css("tr"):
...     specs[td.css("td")[0].css("::text").extract_first()] = td.css("td")[1].css("::text").extract_first()
... 
>>>  Can I execute this in scrapy shell?

Comment: What did you get? And yes, I executed that code in scrapy shell

Comment: Nothing. I received just the prompt: >>>

Comment: LOL, looks like you are doing it for the first time, first write `for td in response.css(".specifications .col.s12.l5")[0].css("tr"):` and then write the next line and then hit enter twice ... I would suggest create a project instead of running it via scrapy shell

Comment: :-) Not much experience, you  are right. However I did it this way. No result just the prompt.

Comment: @merlin after hitting enter did you print `specs` variable?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185042/discussion-between-merlin-and-umair).

Comment: @merlin sorry  cant reply to Chat now ... can you ask your question here? or add me on skype: mani619cash